Как разобрать слово "ученик" по составу? Очень трудный вопрос
Как разобрать по составу  слово ученик? Можно посмотреть в Сети в учебных материалах:

Карта слов. Образовака.

Вот их разбор: уч/е/ник. Интересное дело, а суффикс Е откуда? Ведь слово образовано от учить(ся)?  На остальных ресурсах примерно то же самое, хотя есть варианты Большой вопрос.

А что говорится в словаре Тихонова: уч/еник.  А что в словаре Потиха (Зиновия Ароновича): уч/ен/ик.

Есть еще Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц Ефремовой: уч/еник.  Словообразовательная единица ЕНИК со значением лица, которое характеризуется действием, названным глаголом: мученик, труженик, ученик.

А это совсем экзотика: уч — корень, е — соединительная гласная, ник — суффикс. Хотя нет, имелась в виду интерфиксация. Может, действительно так? А как же Тихонов?


Какой же вариант выбрать?  Ну и вопросы к составителям учебных материалов: чем они руководствовались в своих решениях и какими словарями пользовались?
